# Set focus on a NSTextField in an NSMenu?

Tags: cocoa, macos, focus, nstextfield, nsmenu

I have an NSMenu in the Mac statusbar, inside it I have a load of NSMenuItems and a custom view. Inside the custom view I have an NSTextField. I want to set the focus on the NSTextField when the menu is opened as in the Spotlight menu so the user can type straight away.

I have tried quite a few methods including:

```
    [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

and

```
    [myTextField selectText: self];
    [[myTextField currentEditor] setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange([[myTextField stringValue] length], 0)];
```

but none of them work.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with the first one, but `-becomeFirstResponder` doesn't actually make your view the first responder--you have to call `-[NSWindow makeFirstResponder:]` for that.

Google suggests that `NSMenu`s actually have an attached window.  You have to use it very carefully, but it is safe to call `makeFirstResponder:` on it.

More information about this and how to take advantage of it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20171113100008/http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/195835-set-focus-on-nsview-in-an-nsmenuitem.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your solution has partially help, when the menu is opened it still does not work even though I call "[[myTextView window] makeFirstResponder: myTextField]", but what does happen is that when I click inside the myTextView it makes the myTextField in focus.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Switched to an archive.org link, thanks.